# Creating an array of objects from react events

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a new object for `ingredient` `quantity` `measure` for each new ingredient the user creates. I can make the object for 1 of the `ingredient-triad` divs but I am stumped about how to create several objects with different ingredients added by user eg.

```
ingredientList = [
 {
   ingredient_name: flour,
   ingredient_quantity: 1,
   ingredient_measure: cup
 },
 {
   ingredient_name: water,
   ingredient_quantity: 1,
   ingredient_measure: tbsp
 }
]

etc.
```

Here is where I have gotten to:

```
export default function Recipe() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [method, setMethod] = useState('')
  const [ingredient, setIngredient] = useState('')
  const [ingredientyQty, setIngredientQty] = useState('')
  const [ingredientMeasure, setIngredientMeasure] = useState('')

  const ingredientList = []

  const recipeIngredient = {
    ingredient_name: ingredient,
    quantity: ingredientyQty,
    measure: ingredientMeasure,
  }

  ingredientList.push(recipeIngredient)

  const sendRecipeName = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/recipe', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, method: method }),
    })
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      [...]
          <div className="ingredient-triad">
            <input
              className="ingredient"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredient(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <input
              className="quantity"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredientQty(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <select
              className="dropdown"
              name="measure"
              id="measure"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredientMeasure(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="cup">cup</option>
              [...]
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="ingredient-triad">
            <input
              className="ingredient"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredient(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <input
              className="quantity"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredientQty(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <select
              className="dropdown"
              name="measure"
              id="measure"
              onChange={(e) => setIngredientMeasure(e.target.value)}
            >
               <option value="cup">cup</option>
              [...]
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="save-button-container">
            <button className="save-recipe" onClick={(e) => sendRecipeName(e)}>
              Submit Recipe
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: are there only two sets of inputs ?

Comment: At this stage - yes, there will be more. I am just building it piece by piece.

Comment: Where your button create one of new object for ingredient.

Comment: Why you use the `ingredientList ` in your code? it declared and not used anywhere

Comment: ``ingredientList.push(recipeIngredient)``?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const init = {
  ingredient_name: "",
  quantity: "",
  measure: ""
};

export default function App() {
  const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState([
    {
      ingredient_name: "",
      quantity: "",
      measure: ""
    }
  ]);

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
   
    setIngredientList((prevState) => {
      const newIngredientList = [...prevState];
      newIngredientList[i][name] = value;
      return [...newIngredientList];
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      [...]
      {ingredientList.map((list, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="ingredient-triad">
          <input
            className="ingredient"
            name="ingredient_name"
            type="text"
            value={list.ingredient_name}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          ></input>
          <input
            className="quantity"
            name="quantity"
            type="text"
            value={list.quantity}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          ></input>
          <select
            className="dropdown"
            name="measure"
            id="measure"
            value={list.measure}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
          >
            <option value="" disabled>
              --none--
            </option>
            <option value="cup">cup</option>
          </select>
          <button onClick={() => setIngredientList((prev) => [...prev, init])}>
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
      [...]
    </>
  );
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go - what was I doing wrong?

Comment: I have not checked your code yet. I think you are not using useState for the list and not updating list array properly

Comment: Can you explain the onClick part of this function - currently it reloads the page and the url updates to include recipeingredient details eg: ``http://localhost:3000/newrecipe?ingredient_name=Oil&quantity=1&measure=cup&ingredient_name=&quantity=``

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
export default function Recipe() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [method, setMethod] = useState('')
    const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState([])
    const [ingredient, setIngredient] = useState('')
    const [ingredientyQty, setIngredientQty] = useState('')
    const [ingredientMeasure, setIngredientMeasure] = useState('')
  
    console.log(ingredientList)
    const sendRecipeName = function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()

      const recipeIngredient = {
        ingredient_name: ingredient,
        quantity: ingredientyQty,
        measure: ingredientMeasure,
      }
      setIngredientList((prev) => [...prev, recipeIngredient])
  
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/recipe', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name: name, method: method }),
      })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((json) => console.log(json))
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        [...]
            <div className="ingredient-triad">
              <input
                className="ingredient"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredient(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                className="quantity"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredientQty(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <select
                className="dropdown"
                name="measure"
                id="measure"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredientMeasure(e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value="cup">cup</option>
                [...]
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="ingredient-triad">
              <input
                className="ingredient"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredient(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                className="quantity"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredientQty(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <select
                className="dropdown"
                name="measure"
                id="measure"
                onChange={(e) => setIngredientMeasure(e.target.value)}
              >
                 <option value="cup">cup</option>
                [...]
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="save-button-container">
              <button className="save-recipe" onClick={(e) => sendRecipeName(e)}>
                Submit Recipe
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this only picks up one ``ingredient`` not both.